# What to use in ANTLR4 to resolve ambiguities (instead of syntactic predicates)?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

In ANTLR v3, syntactic predicates could be used to solve e.g., the dangling else problem. ANTLR4 seems to accept grammars with similar ambiguities, but during parsing it reports these ambiguities (e.g., "line 2:29 reportAmbiguity d=0 (e): ambigAlts={1, 2}, input=..."). It produces a parse tree, despite these ambiguities (by chosing the first alternative, according to the documentation). But what can I do, if I want it to chose some other alternative? In other words, how can I explicitly resolve ambiguities?

For example, the dangling else problem:

```
prog
    :   e EOF
    ;

e
    :   'if' e 'then' e ('else' e)?
    |   INT
    ;
```

With this grammar, from the input "if 1 then if 2 then 3 else 4", it builds this parse tree: (prog (e if (e 1) then (e if (e 2) then (e 3) else (e 4))) ).

What can I do, if for some reason, I want the other tree: (prog (e if (e 1) then (e if (e 2) then (e 3)) else (e 4)) ) ?

Edit: for a more complex example, see [What to use in ANTLR4 to resolve ambiguities in more complex cases (instead of syntactic predicates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441651/what-to-use-in-antlr4-to-resolve-ambiguities-in-more-complex-cases-instead-of-s))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can explicitly disallow an alternative in this type of situation by using a semantic predicate.

  ```
  ('else' e | {_input.LA(1) != ELSE}?)
  ```
- You should be able to use the `??` operator instead of `?` to prefer associating the `else` with the outermost `if`. However, performance will suffer substantially. Another option is distinguishing matched `if`/`else` pairs separately from an unmatched `if`.

  ```
  ifStatement
    : 'if' expression 'then' (statement | block) 'else' (statement | block)
    | 'if' expression 'then' (statementNoIf | block)
    ;
  ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However I'm not sure how to use these solutions to solve other ambiguities, so I've added another example to my original question.

Comment: @user3246110 Please create a new question so I can answer it separately. The most common case is if/if/else, so I'd like to keep this answer short and to the point for those users.

Comment: Thanks, I've created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441651/what-to-use-in-antlr4-to-resolve-ambiguities-in-more-complex-cases-instead-of-s

Comment: Thanks! I never could make the 2nd part work without a `reportAttemptingFullContext`, but the first is the easiest, even if it looks a little bit like black magic in the grammar ;-)