# What to use in ANTLR4 to resolve ambiguities in more complex cases (instead of syntactic predicates)?

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

In ANTLR v3, syntactic predicates could be used to solve ambiguitites, i.e., to explicitly tell ANTLR which alternative should be chosen. ANTLR4 seems to simply accept grammars with similar ambiguities, but during parsing it reports these ambiguities. It produces a parse tree, despite these ambiguities (by chosing the first alternative, according to the documentation). But what can I do, if I want it to chose some other alternative? In other words, how can I explicitly resolve ambiguities?

(For the simple case of the dangling else problem see: [What to use in ANTLR4 to resolve ambiguities (instead of syntactic predicates)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415917/what-to-use-in-antlr4-to-resolve-ambiguities-instead-of-syntactic-predicates))

A more complex example:

If I have a rule like this:

```
expr
    :   expr '[' expr? ']'
    |   ID expr
    |   '[' expr ']'
    |   ID
    |   INT
    ;
```

This will parse `foo[4]` as `(expr foo (expr [ (expr 4) ]))`. But I may want to parse it as `(expr (expr foo) [ (expr 4) ])`. (I. e., always take the first alternative if possible. It is the first alternative, so according to the documentation, it should have higher precedence. So why it builds this tree?)

If I understand correctly, I have 2 solutions:

1. Basically implement the syntactic predicate with a semantic predicate (however, I'm not sure how, in this case).
2. Restructure the grammar.

For example, replace `expr` with `e`:

```
e   :   expr | pe
    ;

expr
    :   expr '[' expr? ']'
    |   ID expr
    |   ID
    |   INT
    ;

pe  :   '[' expr ']'
    ;
```

This seems to work, although the grammar became more complex.

I may misunderstood some things, but both of these solutions seem less elegant and more complicated than syntactic predicates. Although, I like the solution for the dangling else problem with the `??` operator. But I'm not sure how to use in this case. Is it possible?

Comment: I updated your example to use the operators `[` and `]` instead of `(` and `)` to make it clear to readers what form the examples have when printed in LISP syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to resolve this by placing the `ID` alternative above `ID expr`. When left-recursion is eliminated, all of your alternatives which are not left recursive are parsed before your alternatives which are left recursive.

For your example, the first non-left-recursive alternative `ID expr` matches the entire expression, so there is nothing left to parse afterwards.

Comment: I've tried placing ID above ID expr. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem, I still get the same tree.

Answer (score 0):

To get this expression (expr (expr foo) [ (expr 4) ]), you can use

> top : expr EOF;

> expr :   expr '[' expr? ']' | ID | INT ;