# ANTLR if-else ambiguity errors

Tags: compiler-construction, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I am trying to create ANTLR grammar for a simple programming language.

It has C-like if statements:

```
program
    : statement* EOF
    ;

statement
    : block                                                                 # blockStatement
    | SEMI                                                                  # emptyStatement
    | assignment                                                            # assignmentStatement
    | declaration                                                           # variableDeclarationStatement
    | 'if' parExpression ifBody=statement ('else' elseBody=statement)?      # ifStatement
    ..........
    ;

block
    : '{' statement* '}'
    ;

expression
    : literal                                                           # literalExpression
    | Identifier                                                        # variableReference
    ..........
    ;

parExpression : '(' expression ')';

assignment : Identifier assignmentOp expression SEMI;

SEMI : ';';

Identifier : (LETTER | '_') (LETTER | DIGIT | '_')* ;
```

It seems to work fine but when I run with `DiagnosticErrorListener` I get errors

```
reportAttemptingFullContext d=1 (statement), input='else', Line 3:0
reportContextSensitivity d=1 (statement), input='else', Line 3:0
reportAttemptingFullContext d=1 (statement), input='else', Line 5:0
reportContextSensitivity d=1 (statement), input='else', Line 5:0
```

for code like this

```
if (flag1)
    x = 42;
else if (flag2)
    x = 43;
else
    x = 44;
```

I am not sure that I understand what is wrong here, but as I understand in other cases (such as `if (a) if (b) ... else ...`) this grammar can be ambiguous.

How should I fix it?

Comment: Why the java tag?

Comment: I believe you don't need to care. What gets reported here is what the parser tried to solve the ambiguity on its own. If the normal parse run returns what you expect then the grammar seems to be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called the *dangling else* problem.
Parsing the text:

```
      if (flag1)
         if (flag2) x=2;
            else x=3;
```

can match your grammar two ways:

```
      if (flag1)
         if (flag2) x=2;
         else x=3; // belongs to if (flag2)
```

and

```
      if (flag1)
         if (flag2) x=2;
      else x=3; // belongs to if (flag1)
```

because you made the else clause an optional match.  This means that the grammar rules provide an ambiguous match, which is the complaint you are getting from ANTLR.

What you want is force the else to match the nearest unclosed if statement; this is the interpretation of  if ... else in most programming languages.

You have to modify the statement parsing rule:

```
statement
    : non_if_statement
    | if_statement
;

if_statement
    : 'if' parExpression 
         ifBody= ( non_if_statement 'else' elseBody=statement
                   | if_statement )
;  

non_if_statement
    :block                                                                 
    | SEMI
    | assignment 
    | declaration
    ..........
;
```

This is a bit awkward to write but should work.

Many parser generators allow you to "force a shift" on encountering a token.  If you force a shift on the else keyword in your original grammar, you'll get the same effect.  I don't know how to say that for ANTLR, if indeed you can.

[Lischke says if you ignore the error, you might get the right result anyway with your original grammar. I think he is right; that's because the parser generator is forced to choose one of the two interpretations as what it accepts.]

Comment: Thank you.
In the code examples, did you mean `if (flag1) if (flag2) ...` (without `x=1;` after the first `if`)?

Comment: Ooops, yes, the x=1; is just a 2 am glitch.  Patched.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this semantic predicate can be used in ANTLR to avoid this warning:

```
'if' parExpression ifBody=statement ('else' elseBody=statement | {_input.LA(1) != ELSE}?)
```

(from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21416927/964478)

Also as I understand from https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/42 a better way exists since 2013: `ifStmt : 'if' ID stmt (options{sll=true;} : 'else' stmt | );` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: This is the only way to make it work, it seems. The other solution by Ira Baxter doesn't take into account the fact 'else' is optional, and trying to add it leads to a `reportAttemptingFullContext` no matter what.

Comment: The `options{sll=true;}:` is not even accepted by ANTLR (4.9.1). Firstly, `options` cannot be placed within rules, it must be at the start of the rule, after the rule name and before the `:`. Secondly `sll` is not a valid option and it does nothing. Even if it did, I'm not sure how it would help because if SLL fails, we should use a slower prediction method. This feature is obscure to me, if it existed at some point like this discussion suggests, it was a temporary attempt that was rolled back.